# Determine if there is a majority element in linear time

Tags: algorithm, computer-science

this is my interview question and I am a bit stumped on it. Given an array of k elements design a linear time algorithm for determining whether the list has a majority element, where a majority element is one which appears more than k/2 times in the list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [Boyer's algorithm](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~moore/best-ideas/mjrty/example.html) that runs in `O(n)` time. It goes through the array two times.

The algorithm uses an initially `candidate` value for the majority element, and a counter `count` which is initially set to zero.

The first pass looks like this:

```
int count = 0;
T candidate = null;
foreach (var element in array) {
    if (count == 0) {
        candidate = element;
        count = 1;
    } else {
        if (candidate == element) {
            count++;
        } else {
            count--;
        }
    }
}
```

If a majority element exists, `candidate` will be equal to it at the end of the loop. However, if there is no majority element, the candidate may contain a false positive. The second pass takes care of that:

```
count = 0;
foreach (var element in array) {
    if (element == candidate) {
        count++;
    }
}
if (count > array.Length/2) {
    Console.WriteLine("Majority element is {0}", candidate);
} else {
    Console.WriteLine("No majority element");
}
```

Comment: In an array like this : {1,2,2,3,4,5} , 2 is the majority element, not necessarily occurring more than n/2times. This algorithm will fail in this case

Comment: @G3M I know I'm really, **really**, late, but in the context of this problem, the majority element is defined as an element appearing at least `n/2` times (where `n` is the length of the list).  The majority element is **not** the mode.  So the algorithm won't fail.

Answer (score 2):

You could hash the elements of the array to integer values, where the values of the elements are the keys of the hash and the values of the hash are the counts of the # of occurrences of each element in the array.  You can also store the maximum # of occurrences as a value max; if max > k/2, the list has a majority element and you don't even need to go through the hash again.

Answer (score 1):

Robert S Boyer and J Strother Moore wrote an algorithm that finds the majority in O(n) time and O(1) space, and can be used on-line, for instance with data stored on magnetic tape (assuming a single rewind). The idea is to keep at all times a candidate winner, incrementing a count by 1 each time the candidate is seen, decrementing the count by 1 each time some other candidate is seen, and resetting the candidate with the current item whenever the count is zero. The surviving candidate is in the majority, if a majority exists; that requires a separate pass through the data, counting the number of appearances of the candidate. Boyer and Moore (the same guys that wrote the string-matching algorithm) wrote a delightful [paper](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/ftp/techreports/tr81-32.pdf) which not only describes the algorithm but also describes a formal proof of their FORTRAN 77 program. I have an implementation in Scheme at [my blog](http://programmingpraxis.com/2011/12/16/majority-voting/).

Answer (score 0):

```
Create Hashmap, with elements as keys and counters as values
For each item
   If the item doesn't have an entry in the hashmap,
       Create a counter, starting with a zero value

   Increment the counter stored in the hashmap
   If the count > k /2
       Then this element is the majority element; return true

There is no max if we reach this line; return false
```